# Binding collection of objects to data from a select list in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose I have a select list:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="Options.Id">
  <option value="value1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="value4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="value5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

When form-submitted to the server, the data will be of the form:

```
Options.Id=value1&Options.Id=value4&Options.Id=value5
```

If Options 1, 4 and 5 are selected.

The default model binder is not able to bind this to a list of objects of type:

```
class MyData 
{
  String Id { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

It will work if the name of the select list is Options and I bind to list of Strings. I suppose the default model binder wants to bind to a list of String called 'Id' which is a member of an objest called Options, is it? Does it look as though I need a default model binder for this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind to an array of objects, you usually have to have an array of fields on the client side to bind to the array on the server side (see here for more info: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx). I think to bind from a single multiselect field to multiple objects on the server side you'll have to write a custom model binder.